# MIN IF and MAX IF in Excel returns #VALUE error, even as an array formula

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, max, min

I want to return the minimum value and maximum value of a range that corresponds to a unique ID code. My version of Excel does not have MINIFS or MAXIFS.

Say that the range AA:AA contains all unique codes, the cell AA2 contains the unique code for row 2, and the range X:X contains all values to pick out the minimum or maximum from.

I have tried using `{=MIN(IF(AA:AA=AA2;X:X))}` and `{=MAX(IF(AA:AA=AA2;X:X))}` as array formulas, but both return a `#VALUE` error.

When entered as regular formulas, `=MIN(IF(AA:AA=AA2;X:X))` and `=MAX(IF(AA:AA=AA2;X:X))` return the minimum and maximum values of the whole of X:X, respectively, ignoring the IF statement.

What's going wrong, here? Is there another solution?

**Edit:** As an example of my data, it's set out as:

```
A    B            C      [...]  X       AA                AB              AC
ID   Date         Variable      Value   Unique ID         Minimum value   Maximum value
101  2018-08-01   Creatinine    40      =ID&Date&Variable =formula       =formula
101  2018-08-01   Creatinine    45      =ID&Date&Variable =formula       =formula
101  2018-08-02   Creatinine    35      =ID&Date&Variable =formula       =formula
```

I am aiming to find the daily minimum and maximum values of each specific test. I created AA as a unique string that specifies by a particular subject ID, date, and test variable. I was hoping that my MIN IF and MAX IF formulas would pick up all values in X:X that would correspond to this unique ID and find the minimum and maximum values.

This method works correctly for averages with `=AVERAGEIF(AA:AA;AA2;X:X)`, which returns 42.5 in rows 2 and 3, and 35 in row 4, for example.

Comment: Can you confirm why you need AA:AA=AA2 in this formula? Isn't that irrelevant? Say column AA contains Apples, Oranges and Bananas. Why does it matter which fruit you are looking up, considering column X doesn't care about fruits? I don't understand it yet based on your formula. Sample data may be helpful.

Comment: Sample data would definitely be helpful here. It's unclear whether AA:AA actually contains all unique codes, given the formula approach you're taking.

Comment: @Isolated In my case, X does care about the identifier in AA. Hopefully my edit clarifies this, but in short AA specifies a particular subject ID, test, and date grouping.

Comment: @BigBen I've added an example table. Column AA is the same formula in every row, so should contain all unique codes.

Answer (score 0):

I took the easier solution of transferring the file to a personal computer that has a more recent version of Excel with MINIFS and MAXIFS functions. If you have a similar problem, it may be worth trying to find a (trusted) computer with either Office 365 or the 2019 version of Excel as a workaround.

I won't mark this as an answer as it doesn't yet explicitly resolve the issue for those without access to Office 365 or Excel 2019.